# How to get jsonp using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to get my json using jsonp

this is my json data [image]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007',
     type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
     contentType: "application/javascript",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

and i always get this error

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007&callback=callback&_=1439798517979' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

here where do i get my json on my rails controller

```
  def conference_participants
      conditions = Hash.new
    if params[:cid]
      conditions[:cid] = params[:cid]
    end

    @conference_participant = ConfbridgeParticipant.where(conditions)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :html => @conference_participant }
        format.text { render :text => @conference_participant.pluck(:id).first }
        format.json { render :json => @conference_participant}
        format.js { render :json => @conference_participant , :callback => params[:callback]}
    end
  end
```

thanks :)

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Comment: my version is ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Okay, and what is your Rails gem version? You can find it out by running `bundle show rails ` in the terminal in your project's folder.